# Not invocable Model Variable on controller Where Statement

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, filter

i have a really silly question but i cant find my self to know why Visual Studio give me this Error.

I maked a filter Text box in my View and i pass the String to my controller to make a where statement using one of my Model Strings and i get the error on my model String saying its not Invocable..
This is my View part of textbox

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
<p>
    Filtro Descripcion: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <input type="submit" value="Seach" />
</p>
}
```

This is my model:

```html
 public partial class Pos
    {
        public System.DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Rid { get; set; }
        public string Pdv { get; set; }
        public string Pla { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }

        
    }
```

This is my Context:

```html
 public partial class ArponClientPosContext : DbContext
    {
        static ArponClientPosContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ArponClientPosContext>(null);
        }

        public ArponClientPosContext()
            : base("Name=ArponClientPosContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Pos> Pos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PosMap());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my controller Index Method that give me the error on my where statement

```html
 public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
        { 
            var db = new ArponClientPosContext();
            var students = from s in db.Pos
                           select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                db = db.Pos.Where(s => s.Descripcion(searchString));
            }

            return View("~/Views/HomePos/Index.cshtml", db.Pos.ToList());
           
        }
```

exactly this part :  db.Pos.Where(s => s.Descripcion(searchString));
it says "Description" is not an invocable object

Can someone explain my why i have this problema or what did i did wrong?
Any help wil be apreciated

Comment: yes but if i add a statement after "DEscripcion" like .equals or contains i get an erro on the whole statemt saying: "i can't convert a type System.Linq.iquery theres already a explicit conversion"

Comment: @ArturoMartinez Can you include your code for ArponclientPosContext?

Comment: of course @thinklarge let me add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to compare Descripcion to your searchString?  Do you want something a perfect match?  If so use .Equals().  If you want it to search Descripcion for anything that "Contains" that text then use .Contains.  If you want to be type insensitive then use a .ToLower on both values within the Where.

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString = "")
    { 
        var db = new ArponClientPosContext();            
        var lowerSearch = searchString.ToLower();
        var students = from s in db.Pos
                   where s.Descripcion.ToLower().Contains(lowerSearch)
                   select s;
        return View("~/Views/HomePos/Index.cshtml", students.ToList());

    }
```

The [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OSGpIA) I used to work this out.

Comment: not a perfect match, i would like to make it like if the search string is "Caf" it will display every item in the where statemt that starts with caf...etc

but it give me the invocable object error at "Descripcion" on my where statement

Also if i use equals it give e an error saying that i cant conver my whole sentence i already have a converted sentence

Comment: @ArturoMartinez I'm assuming that db.Pos is of type List<Pos>.  If it is of type Pos then you can't do this.

Comment: i have it like a dbSet, i just edited so my context was uploaded @thinklarge

Comment: @ArturoMartinez I changed my answer, I dropped your where clause because you can get it from the select statement above.  I've got a contrived example of your application on DotFiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/OSGpIA